# Failed to run terminal app by .desktop file

Tags: command-line, 18.04, .desktop, dotnet

I have following desktop file entries.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=TestClient.desktop
GenericName=Test
Comment=Test
Exec=/usr/share/TestClient/TestClientService
Path=/usr/share/TestClient
Icon=/usr/share/TestClient/Test.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
```

When I double click on desktop file then nothing happens. How to check log in Ubuntu that what is happening?

If I run `./TestClientService` in terminal  then it is successfully run, means there is no issue with any dependency or console app self.

**Note:** I have checked property of desktop file to run as executable.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this will help, but you seem to be missing the `Version=1.0` line right below the `[Desktop Entry]` line.

Comment: Version information was added. It was missing in my question by mistake. I have updated question but the problem is still.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the .Desktop file and Click allow launching.

[DESKTOP_FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfEL8.png)

Comment: Please read Note 2. It is has been done already. https://postimg.cc/YvZFfcDB  [url=https://postimg.cc/YvZFfcDB][img]https://i.postimg.cc/YvZFfcDB/q1.jpg[/img][/url]